# Store multidimensional numpy array slice with newaxis to object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have some code where I repeatedly need to repeatedly broadcast arrays in complex ways, for example:

```
a = b[np.newaxis, ..., :, np.newaxis] * c[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
```

Is there an object to which I can store these slicing specifications?

i.e. (but obviously this doesn't work):

```
s1 = magic([np.newaxis, ..., :, np.newaxis])
s2 = magic([..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :])
```

---

Edit: perhaps this could be done with [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html), but it's unclear how exactly while making sure that the correct axes are broadcast over...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct the index tuple manually, but NumPy includes a [helper](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html#numpy.s_) for it:

```
slice_tuple = np.s_[np.newaxis, ..., :, np.newaxis]
```

Then `b[np.newaxis, ..., :, np.newaxis]` is equivalent to `b[slicetuple]`.

---

For reference, constructing the tuple manually would be `(np.newaxis, Ellipsis, slice(None), np.newaxis)`. Also, `np.newaxis is None`, so `(None, Ellipsis, slice(None), None)` would be equivalent.

---

`np.s_` can be reimplemented yourself as follows:

```
class IndexHelper(object):
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        return arg

s_ = IndexHelper()
```

Comment: Thank you!  Ugh, I was stupidly thinking that you couldn't store an ellipses to a tuple (for whatever reason...).  Why would the 'helper' be preferred to manually?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix: It's just convenient.